# Go performance penalty in high number of calls to append

Tags: go

I'm writing an emulator in Go, and for debugging purposes I'm logging the cpu' state at every emulator's cycle to generate a log file later.

There's something I'm not doing properly because while the logger is enabled performance drops and makes the emulator unusable.

Profiler shows clearly the culprit resides in the logging routine (`logStep` method):
[image]

`logStep` method is very simple, it calls `CreateState` to snapshot current cpu state in a struct, and then adds it to a slice (in method `Log`).
I call this method at every emulated cpu cycle (around 30.000 times per second), and I suspect either Garbage Collector is slowing my execution or I'm doing something wrong with this data structure.

I get the profile graph is pointing me to `runtime growslice` caused by an `append` located in `(*cpu6502Logger)Log`, but I'm unable to find information on how to do this more efficiently.
Also, I scratch my head on why `CreateState` takes that long to just create a simple struct.

This is what `CpuState` looks like:

```
type CpuState struct {
    Registers          Cpu6502Registers
    CurrentInstruction Instruction
    RawOpcode          [4]byte
    EvaluatedAddress   Address
    CyclesSinceReset   uint32
}
```

This is how I create a CPU Snapshot:

```
func CreateState(cpu Cpu6502) CpuState {
    pc := cpu.Registers().Pc

    var rawOpcode [4]byte
    rawOpcode[0] = 0x00
    pc++
    instruction := cpu.instructions[rawOpcode[0]]

    for i := byte(0); i < (instruction.Size() - 1); i++ {
        rawOpcode[1+i] = cpu.memory.Read(pc+Address(i))
    }

    _, evaluatedAddress, _, _ := cpu.addressEvaluators[instruction.AddressMode()](pc)

    state := CpuState{
        *cpu.Registers(),
        instruction,
        rawOpcode,
        evaluatedAddress,
        cpu.cycle,
    }

    return state
}
```

And finally, how I add this snapshot to a collection (`log` method in the profile graph). I've also addde how I initialize `logger.snapshots`:

```
func createCPULogger(outputPath string) cpu6502Logger {
    return cpu6502Logger{
        outputPath: outputPath,
        snapshots: make([]CpuState, 0, 10024),
    }
}

func (logger *cpu6502Logger) Log(state CpuState) {
    logger.snapshots = append(logger.snapshots, state)
}
```

Comment: are you creating new logger each time you log?

Comment: no @JakubDóka, the logger is just created once, outside the "main loop"

Comment: This looks like quite a lot more work than emulating a single CPU instruction, so it doesn't seem surprising that it takes up most of the runtime.

Comment: and you are appending logs to the same logger all the time?

Comment: yes, I'm appending the logs to the same logger all the time.

Comment: there we have it i have an answer

Comment: @JakubDóka, the logger holds the snapshots for the whole execution. At the end of emulation, the snapshots are persisted to a file.

Comment: We can optimize it sure thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Disclaimer: following text contains grammar mistakes but i dont give a damn</s>

### why is it slow

Maintaining one gigantic slice to hold all data there is is wery costy mainly when it constantly extends. Each time you append few elements, whole memory section is copied to bigges section to allow expansion. with grownig slice, complexity grows and each realocation is slower and slower. You told us that you emulate tousands of cpu states per second.

### solution

The best way to deal with this is allocating fixed buffer of some length. Now we now that eventually we will run out of space. When that happens we have two options. First you can write all data ftom buffer to file then truncate the buffer and start filling again (then write again). Other option is to save filled buffers in a slice and allocate new one. Choos witch one fits your machine. (slow or small ram is not good for second solution)

### why does this help

i think this also helps the emulator it self. There will be performance spikes when restoring buffer, but most of the time, performance will be at maximum. Allocating big memory is just slow as alocator is less likely to find fitting section on first try. Garbage collection is also wery unhappy with frequent allocations. By allocating buffer and filling it, we use one big allocation, (but not too big), and store data in sections. Sections we already saved can stey where they are. We can also say that in this case we are handling memory our selfs more then gc does. (no garbage memory produced)

Comment: makes totally sense, I changed accordingly and now the bottleneck has jumped somewhere else (more specifically, inside the write to file function where I serialize to string all snapshots).
Thank you!

Comment: @Pherrymason, you can also consider using a data structure that doesn't have to re-allocate, such as a [linked list](https://golang.org/pkg/container/list/).

Comment: What do you mean @Peter? You dont need linked list to preven realocations. I explaned strategi in my answer.

Comment: Saving to disk every now and then (as opposed to once at the end) is obviously slow. Copying the slice requires allocation.